# npm installation errors with packages

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-gyp

For some reason my node package manager broke and I can't use it.
When running any install command I get a ton of error messages which I have no clue how to fix them.

I am quite new to node so forgive me if this might be straight forward but I couldn't fix it with a Google search. I should note that I have completely reinstalled npm and nodejs.

How do I fix this?

```
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /var/www/dev/ivrm/wp-content/themes/roots/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh /tmp/postinstall-34823128.sh
npm ERR! Building: /usr/bin/node /var/www/dev/ivrm/wp-content/themes/roots/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! make: Entering directory '/var/www/dev/ivrm/wp-content/themes/roots/node_modules/node-sass/build'
```

```
npm ERR! make: Leaving directory '/var/www/dev/ivrm/wp-content/themes/roots/node_modules/node-sass/build'
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/var/www/dev/ivrm/wp-content/themes/roots/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.6.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if "python3" can be used
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "python3" to get executable path
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executable path is "/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "/usr/bin/python3" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - version is "3.8.10"
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.10 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 18.6.0
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '18.6.0' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "18.6.0"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 18.6.0
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 18.6.0
```

```
npm ERR! make: Leaving directory '/var/www/dev/ivrm/wp-content/themes/roots/node_modules/node-sass/build'
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/var/www/dev/ivrm/wp-content/themes/roots/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.6.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if "python3" can be used
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "python3" to get executable path
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executable path is "/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "/usr/bin/python3" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - version is "3.8.10"
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.10 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 18.6.0
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '18.6.0' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "18.6.0"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 18.6.0
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 18.6.0
```

(Unfortunately I can't paste my entire error log in here, I hope this is enough)